# Show/hide <li> by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have html like

```
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li class="dropdown">text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li class="dropdown">text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
<li>text</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {display:none;}
li.dropdown {display:block;}
```

When we click on `li.dropdown`, all the `<li>` without classes, from the current to the next `li.dropdown`, should become visible. And opposite action when we click it again - hide `<li>` without class `dropdown`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be with submenus, so:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">text
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    etc...
</ul>
```

You can then do

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil):

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('li.dropdown').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

This will have the disadvantage of hiding each of the nested `li` elements individually, rather than as a block.  Do the first if you can.

Comment: I cant change html structure.

Comment: @Rooney You can still change the HTML structure with jQuery (if you really need to show/hide them as a block). Otherwise nextUntil should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a nested list structure lik this:

```
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">text
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">text
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Creat a CSS like this:

```
li.dropdown ul {
    display : none;
}
```

And then only show/hide the nested unordered lists:

```
$('li.dropdown').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the item in $dropdown variable then you can use this:

```
$dropdown.next( "li:not(.dropdown)" ).hide();
```

That will hide all not .dropdowns;

To do this until the next .dropdown you will need to use:

```
$dropdown.next("li").each(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".dropdown").toggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2YHC/)